# Checking if a type is a struct or pointer at compile time in C?

Tags: c, c-preprocessor

NOTE: This is *NOT* a duplicate of the question linked by Paul T, because I am asking if it is possible to determine if a type is of a certain broader incomplete type/kind at compile time, not if a symbol has been registered at compile time. This seems like a fundamental misunderstanding of the question.

I am writing a library in C that deals with pseudo-generic functions which take a type as an argument through a macro wrapper.

To spare the details (because they are rather complicated) there are two possible features that could help, I think:

- Being able to detect if a type is a pointer at compile time. (No, the "use _Generic to test if you get ptrdiff_t from subtraction" trick won't work, because structures are a possibility, and you can't subtract structures.)
- Being able to detect if a type is a struct at compile time. (If this was possible, then the aforementioned _Generic trick could be used if the type was detected as not being a struct.)

I've tried everything I could think of on Godbolt (even trying to compare types to incomplete anonymous structs and toying with __builtin_types_compatible_p) and wasn't able to find any solutions.

If anyone has any solutions I'd love to see them, otherwise I may just end up having to complicate the design a bit-- so not the end of the world if it's impossible, but it would be ideal if it can be done.

To give a basic idea of what one of these macros might look like or their expected output:

```
int *a;
assert(!IS_STRUCT(a));
assert(IS_POINTER(a));
struct {} b;
assert(IS_STRUCT(b));
assert(!IS_POINTER(b));
```

shouldn't throw any errors.

Comment: Would `(void) &((object_of_unknown_type)[0]);` meet your goal "to detect if a type is a pointer"?

Comment: @PaulT. That's not at all the same thing though. That's checking if a type is defined at compile time, mine is querying if a type is of a certain kind at compile time.

Comment: @chux I don't see what that's supposed to do? I can certainly just dereference to get a compile-time error if a type isn't a pointer, but as the post demonstrated with the macro examples, I want to actually be able to get this as a static result-- perhaps my use of `assert` for the example was misleading, in which case I apologize.

Comment: Yes I think there is a way - just need to recall the "trick", hmmm.

Comment: Sounds like you seek the ability to always compile `bool tf = IS_STRUCT(a);` (a static result) as you apparently do not want the compilation to stop. (error).  Is that so?

Comment: @chux Correct. Ideally that `IS_STRUCT()` result would also be a constant expression.

Comment: What is a `void*` pointer to a `struct`? What about a pointer to a `struct`? What about non-struct, non-pointers?

Comment: Certainly `#define IS_STRUCT_SUBSTANTIAL(x) (sizeof(x) > sizeof(void*))`, when true, `x` must be a `struct` and not an object pointer. Of course, when false, `x` could be a pointer or a wee `struct`.  Likely not generic enough, but a step.  Knowing how this is used in the larger picture may help.

Comment: Your text says you want to detect if a TYPE is a pointer or struct (ans you say you have the type available as an argument in your macro wrappers), yet your example macros use an IDENTIFIER as a parameter. Did you mean to say you'd like to detect if an IDENTIFIER is of type pointer or a struct?

Comment: @chux Good idea! Closest solution so far, though I would like to try and avoid false positives.

Comment: @GuntherSchulz Fair question-- in the case of my library I make use of the `typeof` GNU extension heavily, so it's somewhat important that the macro be able to take actual type info and not just the plaintext name of the type.

Comment: This is contradicting. You say "detect if a type is...", then you show a pseudo code example about "detect if a variable is of type...". That's not the same. Which one do you want? Should your macro get passed a type or a variable instance?

Comment: @Lundin Yea, in retrospect it could have been better worded-- but essentially I want it to take either actual type info or a variable and extract the variable's type using typeof.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Complete Answer (if EDG Front End used):

If your IDE / compiler is using the EDG C++ Front End (which a lot are), and you are using **C**, not C++ (which your tag suggests), and you say you ARE using typeof, then you can detect a structs as follows ([see the latest manual, page 75](https://www.edg.com/docs/edg_cpp.pdf)):

```
/* Test if EDG Front End is used*/
#if defined(__EDG__) && defined(__EDG_VERSION__)
#define IS_STRUCT(expression_or_type_name) __is_class(typeof (expression_or_type_name)))
#endif
```

since in **C** *__is_class()* will only be true for a *struct* (http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/type_traits/is_class/).

Further, pointers can similarly be detected as follows:

```
/* Test if EDG Front End is used*/
#if defined(__EDG__) && defined(__EDG_VERSION__)
#define IS_POINTER(expression_or_type_name) (__is_convertible_to(typeof (expression_or_type_name), void*) || __is_convertible_to(typeof (expression_or_type_name), void const*) || __is_convertible_to(typeof (expression_or_type_name), void volatile*) || __is_convertible_to(typeof (expression_or_type_name), void const volatile*))
#endif
```

(http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/type_traits/is_convertible/)

Answer (score 0):

1. It’s not possible in standard C. Whatever solutions there may be must be implementation-defined.
2. It seems that C is not a suitable language for your problem domain. Short of esoteric platforms that come without C++ support, there seems to be little reason to have to solve this in C. On most any platform where C is available, so is C++. Since you claim that you use gcc, then C++ is surely available and you can process some of the input using a C++ compiler. You could do the input processing as a generator step: run the code through a C++ compiler to generate source code that defines constants that capture type properties sought.

Comment: 1. Fair, though realistically I don't think many people use compilers outside of gcc/msvc/clang, so raw standard C compliance isn't really a concern. 2. Again fair, but I would prefer to use C. C++ brings other baggage with it and leaves behind some things, it's not a superset of C.