# Can I determine whether the type is a pointer type in C?

Tags: c, metaprogramming

What do I know is that C has [_Generic macros](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7256203/how-to-implement-a-generic-macro-in-c). One can even implement some limited `typename()` for ANSI C (just like it is mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9804371/syntax-and-sample-usage-of-generic-in-c11)).

But can I implement something like [std::is_pointer](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/type_traits/is_pointer/) in C?
For example:

```
#define IS_POINTER_TYPE(x) // ?

struct Vec2 {
    float x;
    float y;
};

int main(int argc, char* argv[], char* env[])
{
    IS_POINTER_TYPE(Vec2*);     // true
    IS_POINTER_TYPE(int*)       // true
    IS_POINTER_TYPE(char)       // false
    IS_POINTER_TYPE(const int)  // false
}
```

Can I do this for variables, not types? Thank you.

UPD:
[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19255148/c-macro-checking-if-a-variable-is-a-pointer-or-not) solution is not portable and not generic unfortunately. One require monkey-job copy-pasting or code generation to make all your structures conform to this notation. You guys guided me to a decision if you don't require 100% accuracy and can tolerate some false-positives.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54452381/checking-if-a-type-is-a-struct-or-pointer-at-compile-time-in-c/54460700#54460700 for a discussion

Comment: @KamilCuk That won't distinguish ptrs from structs/unions/enums/arrays.

Comment: Sidenote: Given how limited language C is, if you find yourself needing this feature often, you are not probably using right language for the job.

Comment: @user694733 You can do a ton a ton of that zero-cost-abstraction high-meta stuff many people think you need C++ for with just C (especially if you include nonstandard but common extensions like `__typeof`, `({ })`, and `__label__`).  Not all of it. This is one of those things that's missing from C.

Answer (score 1):

No unless you know what type of pointer it could be. I don't know of any nonstandard gcc/clang extension that can accomplish it either. The closest thing to it that you can do is a comptime assert that something is a pointer, e.g., with `(void const*){TheThing}` (will also accept zero literals as those can be used null pointers and arrays (you can use `_Generic` to weed those  out)) or by applying a pointer op (`*`, `[0]`) to it while using `_Generic` with `__typeof` to weed out arrays.